# Retrieving first less than value in a joined table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the 3 following tables:
[image]

I want to get a table that consist of three columns which are:

order_id

last order status before contact time

status_description

So the desired output is highlighted in red in the order_status table

I managed to get all the order status before contact time but the required is only 1 for each order_id (I added  the column Timestamp for illustration):

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_status_id, m.status_description, o.Timestamp
FROM
    contact c
        JOIN
    order_status o ON o.order_id = c.order_id
        JOIN
    meta_status m ON o.order_status_id = m.order_status_id
    WHERE o.Timestamp < c.Contact_time 
ORDER BY o.order_id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_status_id, m.status_description, o.Timestamp,row_number() over(partition by o.order_id order by o.Timestamp desc) as rn
FROM
    contact c
        JOIN
    order_status o ON o.order_id = c.order_id
       left JOIN
    meta_status m ON o.order_status_id = m.order_status_id
    where o.Timestamp < c.Contact_time 
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much. But I can see that in the result it skipped the highlighted row for order_id number 2 (where order status is 9) it picked the one above it. I guess this is because there is no order_status_id 9 in the "meta_status" table. Is there a way to make this row appear in the output?

Comment: You can use left join instead of inner join- that could help you @AhmedA

Comment: @AhmedA, I've updated the answer - you can give a try

Comment: @AhmedA, check now

Comment: @AhmedA, glad that it helped u. You can put an upvote  too:)